# Strange error with Tooltips and TitleWindow

Tags: apache-flex, tooltip

I'm developing an application with TitleWindows that are created using the PopUpManager so they can be dragged. Buttons on a ButtonBar display them. After some testing, I found out that the error below is triggered when I am displaying the TitleWindow for the third time (not first or second, but only third) and I try to retrieve the ToolTip from either the Button on the ButtonBar or the TabNavigator in the TitleWindow (by hovering the mouse over these components).

```
RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::rawChildren_addChildAt()
    at mx.managers::SystemChildrenList/addChild()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/addChildToSandboxRoot()
    at mx.managers::ToolTipManagerImpl/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::createTip()
    at mx.managers::ToolTipManagerImpl/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::showTimer_timerHandler()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Also, when I try clicking the Button to display the TitleWindow for the fourth time and I'm faster than the ToolTip to avoid the error, I get this error:

```
RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::rawChildren_addChildAt()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/addChild()
    at mx.managers::PopUpManagerImpl/addPopUp()
    at mx.managers::PopUpManager$/addPopUp()
    at assets.components::FloatingWindow/show()
    at MethodInfo-1879()
```

I have a FloatingWindow class (attached) which extends TitleWindow, and then I'm creating a new class called SearchWindow which extends the FloatingWindow. The ButtonBar is in a class that extends HBox. The ButtonBar has the following function to display the SearchWindow:

```
function searchButton_click(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                //Show Search Window
                if (searchWindow.removed == true)
                {
                    searchWindow.map = _map;
                    searchWindow.webService = wsGetData;
                    searchWindow.show(30);
                }

            }
```

The pattern of this error is strange. Why just on the 3rd time do I get the error with the ToolTip and 4th time with the Poping up the TitleWindow? Could part of the problem be my leap-frogging of classes? I have a custom ButtonBar class, where the SearchWindow is created, which is a custom class based off another custom class (FloatingWindow), which is based off TitleWindow. Can this be the cause of the problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for memory leaks. Maybe your window is not removed from memory and TooltipManager keeps reference to previously opened instance. Ist's a blind shot.

Comment: This took care of it. I just set the instance to null in the Close handler. The answer above did help one I did this as well, since I needed to check if the instance already existed before creating and showing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your searchwindow hasn't been created yet. Try this:

```
function searchButton_click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //Show Search Window
    if (searchWindow && searchWindow.removed)
    {
        searchWindow.map = _map;
        searchWindow.webService = wsGetData;
        searchWindow.show(30);
    }
}
```

This should at least stop the errors from happening.

Comment: This was helpful once I did my garbage collection on the instances floating around.